# PHP - copy() fails on URL with curly braces/brackets

Tags: php, url, str-replace

I'm having an issue with the copy() function in PHP.

I need to copy a remote URL that looks like: `https://example.co.uk/{8d988e90-a325-4a1c-a340-a489166286b8}/{14409287-2c29-4b51-91e4-0891b5619659}/main/imgnew-(2).jpg`, to my local drive.

Here is the part of my code that fails, along with some context for the **$RemoteURL** variable:

```
$replace = array('%7B', '%7D','%28','%29');
$entities = array('{', '}','(',')');
$RemoteURL = str_replace($entities, $replace, "https://example.co.uk/{8d988e90-a325-4a1c-a340-a489166286b8}/{14409287-2c29-4b51-91e4-0891b5619659}/main/imgnew-(2).jpg");

$PicName = "new.jpg"

if(copy($RemoteURL,"C:\Users\Me\Downloads\Pictures\" . $PicName)){
    echo "<script>console.log(\"(" . $RemoteURL . ") copied to waiting.\")</script>";
} else {
    echo "<p class='float red'>READ ERROR</p>";
}
```

However, this throws the error:

```
Warning: copy(https://example.co.uk/%7B8d988e90-a325-4a1c-a340-a489166286b8%7B/%7B14409287-2c29-4b51-91e4-0891b5619659%7B/main/imgnew-%282%29.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

What is it exactly I'm missing here, or what is it that PHP doesn't like about the URL itself?

Comment: My browser encodes { and }, but not (), so you may try to remove this part of the encoding

Comment: @MaximKrizhanovsky Didn't work with just removing the (), thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue that was producing the error above was that I had an accented character that was problematic.

è was giving an error, which was fixed by creating a function that replaced certain parts:

```
function URLEncodeRules($string) {
    $replacements = array('%C3%A9','%C3%A8');
    $entities = array('é','è');
    return str_replace($entities, $replacements, $string);
}

$RemoteURL = URLEncodeRules($CaptureRow['URL']);

if(copy($RemoteURL,"image.jpg")){
   echo "Success!;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `url_encode();`

Hope this will help you.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work - it exchanged every symbol and failed on every copy. Thank you for the suggestion, though